# condition true means inside if condition not executed in android

Tags: php, android

Hi In My Application clicking the login button checks whether the username and password exist in the database or not.

Now, my problem is after clicking this login button, the response from PHP is user found.

After, the condition `if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))` is checked in the data variable which shows user found. It then goes to the else condition. The condition in the if is not checked.

Can anyone please help me?

**class file**

```
 login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String username = usname.getText().toString();
               String password = pword.getText().toString();
               if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
                   if (username.equals("")) {
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER USERNAME",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   }
                   if (password.equals("")) {
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER PASSWORD",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   }

               } else if (!CheckUsername(username) && !CheckPassword(password)){
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER VALID USERNAME & PASSWORD",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               else{
                   final String queryString = "username=" + username + "&password="
                    + password;
                   final String data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("login",queryString);

            System.out.println("data :: "+data);
         tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + data);

            if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
            {

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
               startActivity(i);           
            }

            else
            {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User not found, check query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
               }                        

            }
         });
```

Comment: have you checked if the data and "User Found" is in same format ignoring uppercase lowercase case?

Comment: You have ask many question with this same code with various problem first of all identify your problem then try to ask question.

Comment: Are you sure that `data` doesn't contain any white spaces and/or other 'hidden' characters? Also, the easiest way to identify the problem is by simply breakpointing the code. Despite your question's title, your problem will have nothing to do with Android, but rather with your own code and/or assumptions.

Comment: For Debugging:data value is this User Found

Comment: MH. can you please tell me

Comment: What does `data.length()` return?